# C# objected oriented

Tags: c#, class

I have the following code:

```
  public class Game
    {
        public Game(int board)
        {

        }

        public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
        {
            return lines;
        }
    }
```

If I instantiate a new object of class "Game" with a parameter of, say, 2:

```
Game game = new Game(2)
```

Is there a way to retrieve (and use) this parameter in the "play" method WITHOUT declaring any other variables outside of these two methods, or defining any other methods as well?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it in a class member variable like

```
public class Game
{
private int board;
    public Game(int board)
    {
       this.board = board;
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    {
        return lines[board];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Game { 
    private int _board;
    public Game(int board) {
        _board = board;
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    {
        //use _board here eg: this._board ...
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `private int board;` member of type int and assign the value of board to it. Then you can access it in the play method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Game { 

    private int Board;
    public Game(int board) {
        Board = board;
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    { 
        //used board here
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Simply create a variable `Board` that can be accessed by the play method

Answer (score 0):

Declare `board` as a member in your class so that all functions can access it. Maybe something like this:

```
public class Game 
{
    private int board;

    // Constructor for game. Initializes a new board
    public Game(int board) 
    {
        this.board = board
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    {
        // Access board
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, since I've seen a couple of answers do this - what's the value in making a private field a `{ get; set; }` property?

Comment: I wanted to do that, but the I don't think the guidelines for the project I'm involved allow it.  Is there no way to get the value directly from the Game object/method?

Comment: Sorry @JoeClay that was a typo. It doesn't make sense to have gettere/setters for a `private` variable. Just used to adding them all the time. Fixed it

Comment: No problem :) Wasn't intended as criticism, just wasn't sure if there was something clever I was missing :p

Comment: @bloomers didn't get your question. You will have to save the `board` input into a member variable

Comment: @bloomers: No - the parameter `board` exists only within the `Game` constructor, and only for as long as that constructor is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

define a [private field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) to hold the value that was passed via the constructor. Then acces this field in your Play-Method:

```
public class Game { 
    private readonly int _Board;
    public Game(int board) {
        _Board = board;
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    {
        //access field here
        var board = _Board;
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest declare *properties* and using *constructor chaining*:

```
 public class Game {
   public Game(int board, List<int> lines) {
     if (board < 0)
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRange("board");
     else if (lines == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("lines"); 

     Board = board;
     Lines = lines; 
   }          

   public Game(int board)
     : this(board, new List<int>()) {
   }

   public Game(List<int> list)
     : this(0, list) {
   }

   public int Board {
     get;
     private set;
   }

   public List<int> Lines {
     get;
     private set;  
   }
 }
```

Typical use:

```
 Game game = new game(3); 

 game.Lines.Add(123); 
 game.Lines.Add(456); 

 // Board: 3; Lines: 123, 456
 Console.Write("Board: {0}; Lines: {1}", game.Board, string.Join(", ", game.Lines));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a second parameter to your play method instead of passing it to constructor as you are doing nothing with it in the constructor.

```
public class Game  
{
    public Game() {}

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines, int board)
    {
        // do whatever you want to do with board here
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the amount of answers is due to the fact that you didn't clarified in your question "where" do you want to use the value of the parameter.

If, as most suspect, you only want to use it inside your class (say any of the class's methods) then a field will be enough and you can use any of the previously given answers. Although secretly I fancy @jon-Lopez-garcia 's one just cause it fits my style and makes no additional assumption.

If, on the other hand, you require access to that value from outside the class's methods then a property is the correct way to go. Check @dmitry-bychenko 's answer, very complete although makes some assumptions that you haven't mentioned as needed features.

Yet, if you want to access it from outside then you have to think also if you want it to be changed from outside because in @dmitry-bychenko 's answer there is no changing from outside (notice the "private set;")

Just for not being short here is what I'd do giving the lack of context:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Board { get; private set; }
    public Game(int board)
    {
        Board = board;
    }

    public List<int> play(List<int> lines)
    {
        //use Board here
        return lines;
    }
}
```

These might be good readings for the topic:

- Learn about properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties
- Learn about fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields
- Learn about access modifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers